# Probabilities - Spam Filtering

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

So I have a practice question for spam filtering what I'm trying to solve.

Given information before the question:

(a) An incoming email message is 9 times more likely to be **not flagged** as a spam than to be flagged.

(b) An incoming email message is 19 times more likely to be **genuine** than to be a spam.

Questions:

(a) What is the probability that an incoming message is flagged as a spam and what
is the probability that an income message is actually a spam?

(b) Assume that an income message is a spam. What is the smallest probability
that it will be flagged as a spam?

(c) Assume that an income message is flagged as a spam. What is the largest
probability that it indeed a spam?

If I'm correct about the given information it should look like this:

[image]

Did I get the "likelihood" correct?
For question (a) is it correct to say incoming message P(Flagged = Spam) = 1/10 = 10%
and how would I calculate the second part of question (a) if it is indeed a spam?

Comment: $\frac{1}{10}$ is ten percent, not one percent. Your diagram looks good.

Answer (score 1):

You have computed the probabilities of being flagged and being spam correctly, (1/10 and 1/20 respectively), but your diagram assumes that flagging and being spam are independent of each other, which is not necessarily the case from the information in the question alone.

Let $F$ be the event that the email is flagged, and $S$ be the event that it is spam. We know $P(F)=0.1$ and $P(S)=0.05$, but not that $P(F \cap S)=0.005$. Parts (b) and (c) of the question build on this idea and look at the possible ranges of $P(F|S)$ and $P(S|F)$ without further knowledge on how the spam filter works.

Comment: Yeah I made a typo in the morning about the 1%. Thanks for the feedback, very helpful.